# Calculating the average by inputing values in a file, code produces wrong output

Tags: python-3.x

'''This simple program will calculate the average using files'''

```
num = 3
try:     #set an exception in case of a file Error

    while num >=0:  '''read in values and place them in a file'''
        value = int(input("Enter values: "))
        my_file = open('my_data.txt', 'w+')
        my_file.write(str(value))
        numbers = my_file.readlines()
        num -=1
    my_file.close()

except IOError:
    print('FILE FAILURE')

'''iterate to find the sum of the values in a file'''
total = 0
    for ln in numbers: 
        total += int(ln)

'''Calculate the average'''
avg = total/len(numbers)
    print("The average is %d"%(avg))#FIXME: does not calculate average
```

Comment: "code produces wrong output" How exactly? You should provide example input and output.  Note that you are opening the file in every iteration which truncates it. Why are you even writing to the file and immediately reading from it?

Comment: @DeepSpace, if I enter values, for example: 2, 4 , 7 , 5. The output is always the third number. In this example 7. Thanks!

Comment: See the rest of my comment as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are opening a file for write, then read from it, and assign it to a variable `numbers`. However this variable is not a list, although you treat it as a list when you do `for ln in numbers`.

Furthermore, you should end a line written to file with `\n`

Based on how I understand your code, you want to:

- Get user input, and write it to file
- From the file, read the numbers
- From the numbers calculate the average

There is a `statistics` module, with the function `mean`, which will do the calculation part for you. The rest, you could (should) structure like the three bullet points above, something like this:

```
from statistics import mean

def inputnumbers(itterations, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as openfile:
        while itterations > 0:
            try:
                value=int(input("value->"))
            except ValueError:
                print('Numbers only please')
                continue   
            openfile.write(str(value) + '\n')
            itterations -= 1

def getaveragefromfile(filename):
    numbers = []
    with open(filename, 'r') as openfile:
        for line in openfile.readlines():
            numbers.append(int(line.replace('\n','')))
    return mean(numbers)

def main():
    filename = r'c:\testing\my_data.txt'
    itterations = int(input('how many numbers:'))
    inputnumbers(itterations, filename)
    average = getaveragefromfile(filename)
    print(average)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```